# How do I build validation into an Observable, and conditionally emit?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable, subscription

An excerpt from an Angular class:

```js
optionalString = new BehaviorSubject<string | undefined>(undefined);
  
// used to show that there may be multiple conditions involved
alwaysTrueFlag = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(true);
                                

ngOnInit(): void {
  combineLatest([
    this.optionalString.pipe(skip(1)),
    this.alwaysTrueFlag
  ]).pipe(tap(([str, flag]) => {
    // I hope `str` is a valid number, but it's getting
    // "forwarded" to `subscribe` anyway...
  })).subscribe(result => explodeIfNotNumber(result));
}

onKeyPress() {
  this.optionalString.next(prompt('please enter a number'));
}
```

Since I can't control what happens in `subscribe`, I'd like to avoid its getting triggered – unless the value obtained from the observable is valid (in this case a valid number).

I could control the source, i.e. this `onKeyPress` here, and check if the entered string may safely be converted to a number, but I can't guarantee that every user of `optionalString` is going to follow this, so I want to build validation into the observable itself.

If I'm going about this the wrong way, please tell me the conventional way of doing it. I haven't been able to find anything useful by googling. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could filter out non-numeric values.

```
import { filter, map, skip, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
..
...
ngOnInit(): void {
  combineLatest([
    this.optionalString.pipe(skip(1)),
    this.alwaysTrueFlag
  ]).pipe(
    map(([str, flag]) => ({str, flag})), // Added to simplify the code in the next steps
    filter(({str}) => !isNaN(Number(str))), // Filter the values and emit only valid numbers
    tap(({str, flag}) => {
      // Only run for valid numbers & numeric values
    })
  ).subscribe(({str}) => explodeIfNotNumber(str));
}
```

Since filter is added, `subscribe` would only be triggered if the input is numeric